# Dirac delta derivatives and discontinuities

Tags: integration, dirac-delta, continuity

I have an integral of the form
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(x) \delta'(x) dx
$$

where

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
a & x<0 \\
b & x>0
\end{cases}
$$
and $\delta'$ is the derivative of the Dirac delta. By the rules of using the Dirac delta, I expect that
$$
I = -f'(0) = (a-b) \delta(x)
$$
and, plotting graphs of functions that may be used to in the limit towards $\delta'$, this certainly looks plausible. Is this above correct, and how would I go about proving it?

Comment: How are you making sense of the idea of an integral $\int f(x) \delta'(x) \mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: Does my edit help?

Comment: You are using a "dummy" variable of integration $x$ which is the same as the variable in the upper limit of the integral. This does not make sense even for regular functions,let alone distributions. Do you mean $\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)\delta'(t)dt$?

Comment: Yes (characters to make se happy)

Comment: @AndersBeta The abuse of notation is not the real issue here.  The real issue is that the square of the Dirac Delta is meaningless.

Comment: Where have I squared a Delta?

Comment: @Eddy $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta'(t)H(t)\,dt=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t)H'(t)\,dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t)\,\delta(t)\,dt$ is nonsensical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This integral is in general not well defined in the theory of distributions. Note that $f(x)$ is not a test function, and it has a singularity at $x=0$. If we try to give a meaning to it one runs into difficulties. Using the step function $H(x)$ one could try to give meaning to $I(x)$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}
I(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}H(x-t)f(t)\delta'(t)\,dt=-\left[\frac{d}{dt}H(x-t)f(t)\right]_{t=0}\\
&=\left[\delta(x-t)f(t)-H(x-t)(a-b)\delta(t)\right]_{t=0}\\
&=\delta(x)f(0)-H(x)(a-b)\delta(0) = \;???\,.
\end{align}$$

If $a\ne b$ you can not make sense of this; $f(0)$ and $\delta(0)$ do not make sense. So $I(x)$ is not a well defined distribution. To give meaning to it you may want to replace $f(t)$ by some smooth version of it (physicists will call doing that "regularization"), but the result will depend on the way you do this "regularization". This is a well known problem when you try to multiply distributions with common singularities.

Comment: The functional actually makes sense and is $0$ for $x<0$.

Comment: A distribution cannot make sense only for x<0 and be meaningless elsewhere. These are not functions. Even a problem in one point can ruin a distribution; for instance, $\delta(x)^2$ is meaningless even though it is zero for $x\ne0$.

Comment: The linear functional $I(x)$ depends on the parameter $x$. It has value $0$ for all $x<0$ and it is undefined for $x\ge 0$.  Note that for $t\le x<0$, $f(t)=a$, and inasmuch as $\delta$ and its derivatives have compact support on $\{0\}$, $\langle \delta',H_x\rangle=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(t)=a+(b-a)H(t)$ and $x<0$, then $\int_{-\infty}^x \delta'(t)f(t)\,dt =\int_{-\infty}^x \delta'(t)a\,dt=0$ since $\delta'$ is of compact support on $\{0\}$.

Next note that there is no meaning to the square of the Dirac Delta as a distribution ([See Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221429/why-is-the-square-of-dirac-delta-function-not-a-distribution)).  Consequenlty, if $f(t)=a+(b-a)H(t)$, then the expressions of this pseudo equalities, $\int_{-\infty}^x \delta'(t)f(t)\,dt=-\int_{-\infty}^x \delta(t)f'(t)\,dt=-\int_{-\infty}^x\delta(t)\,\left((b-a)\delta(t)\right)\,dt$, are meaningless for all $x\ge 0$.

Comment: Add your explanation as to where the square of the Dirac Delta comes from (from comment on op) and I'll accept

Comment: @Eddy I've edited as you've requested.