# Integral of the square of the Dirac delta

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

What is the following integral?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta^2(x) {\,\rm d} x$$

I think it should be one, by Parseval's Theorem.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo I don't know enough latex. So I just mentioned that in there.

Comment: Distributions cannot be multiplied. You can only sum them. So basically there is no value, just like for 0/0. But of course you may try to define it somehow. In any case it would be kind of trick/, regularisation and answer will depend on procedure you propose

Comment: @kakaz But how is the integral of dirac delta 1?

Comment: Dirac Delta is element of certain scheme - effect of limiting procedure. It works flawlessly every time, for sums. Multiplication doesn't work. The space of distributions is linear space with norm ( Banach or even Hilbert space). There is no multiplication in general defined on elements of such space

Comment: Alright, I got it.

Comment: Here's a previous Question on this topic: [Why is the square of Dirac delta function not a distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221429/why-is-the-square-of-dirac-delta-function-not-a-distribution)  In some contexts it will make sense to say the integral of "it" is "infinity".

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as $\delta^2(x)$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta^2(x) {\,\rm d} x$.

Nevertheless, there is a natural extension of the $L^2$ norm to the distributions, which of course assigns $\infty $ to $\delta$ and many others.

Take any $\phi \in C^\infty_c(-1,1),\phi \ge 0,\|\phi\|_{L^1}=1$, $\phi_n(x)=n\phi(nx)$ then $$\|T\|_{L^2} = \lim \sup_{n\to \infty} (\int_{-\infty}^\infty |T\ast \phi_n(x)|^2dx)^{1/2},\qquad T\ast \phi_n(x)= \langle T,\phi_n(x-.)\rangle$$

It is an interesting exercice to show (using the Fourier series of $ (T\ast \phi_n)\psi$) that $\|T\|_{L^2}$ is finite iff the distribution $T$ is (represented by) a function in $L^2$. Moreover $\|T\|_{L^2}=\|\hat{T}\|_{L^2}$.

Note that the same idea gets more complicated for $L^1$ : $\delta$ is a finite measure but it is not in $L^1$.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit your answer? For example how should I treat an expression like $\int \delta^2(x-x_0)f(x) dx$?

Answer (score -1):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta^2(x) dx=2\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx$$